# How to change the condition of an interaction

Tags: openlayers

How can I change the condition of an exiting interaction? Or do I have to remove the interaction and create a new one with the desired condition? For example I would like to switch the condition of the DragZoom interaction back and forth from ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly to having no condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating the interaction, set the `condition` to a function that returns boolean.

Then in that function, based on your desired conditions, you can pass it to `ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly` or return `false`

```
var interaction = new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
    condition: function(e) {
        if (shouldTestForShiftKey) {
            return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(e);
        } else {
            return false; //No condition, disable
        }
    }
});
```

Then it's up to you to determine when `shouldTestForShiftKey` should be `true` or `false`